# Can't create an Angular 5 project using angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a new Angular 5 project. I've installed @angular/cli version 1.6.3 and typed:

```
ng new project --routing
```

After everything has been installed I did:

```
cd project
ng build
```

And got the following errors:

> Module build failed: Error: d:...\project\src\main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
>
> Module build failed: Error: d:...\project\src\polyfills.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

There are a couple of discussions about this on the [Angular github page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8713), but other than saying this has been resolved, or pointing to an issue where there where `ts` files in `node_modules` - it was not helpful.

We're using Windows 10 here.

EDIT: the tsconfig files are (there are two):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The other (src/tsconfig.app.json):

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

These were both created by `ng new`.

Comment: Already tried to uninstall and reinstall angular/cli?

Comment: Yes. And again, this happened on several computers. Downgrading to angular-cli 1.4.4 fixes this problem, but uses Angular 4 and not 5. This is what we're going to do for now, but it's hardly a solution.

Comment: Can you post tsconfig?

Comment: Posted, although I doubt they will help. Adding an `include` section to either of them did not help.

Comment: There should be another one called `tsconfig.json`. Can you post that too?

Comment: There's one for testing, it includes test.ts, and .d.ts and .spec.ts files.

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: @pwavg, it was, I forgot to post an answer. Sorry, just posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, I forgot to answer this question! It was answered in the Angular github a long time ago.

In Angular 5 you need to add `--preserve-symlinks` to both `ng build` and `ng serve`.

In Angular 6 you can no longer do that, and instead you need to add

```
 "preserveSymlinks": true,
```

to `angular.json`, you put it under `architect/build/options` of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are running at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x by running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older versions produce errors, but newer versions are fine.

Comment: I'm using node 8.9 and npm 5.5.1